# Hadoop ignoring mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize, when creating splits

Tags: hadoop, split, hadoop-yarn

We're using HDP2.5 and have a job that handles some rows from HBase. I set start key and end key for job and also trying to set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` to increase amount of mappers, but independently of the split maxsize value I get 25 map tasks...

I tried a few values that are 2,4,8 times smaller then `dfs.blocksize`. E.g.

`mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=67108864
dfs.blocksize=134217728`

Enabling logs of application manager did not reveal any useful tips about how YARN decides, on the amount of map tasks. I just see messages like:

`INFO util.RegionSizeCalculator: Calculating region sizes for table "my_table"
...
INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:25`

What would be the right way to bump up the number of map tasks for the job?

Answer (score 0):

The map tasks by default in HBaseMapReduceUtil map to the number of regions.  At Splice Machine (Open Source), we generate more cutpoints by interrogating the hbase store files.  We also added an approach where we read the store files directly with incremental deltas from the the memstore vs. reading remotely from HBase (Slow).

I can post a link to the code if you are interested?